# How to get the correct formatting for my first form?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am having some issues with formatting of my form - I am only new to web coding so I apologise for what may seem very simple - this is my first form I'm coding.

Essentially what I am trying to do is:

- On a screen and tablet: form labels to be right and justified, against form elements
- On a phone: form labels to be left aligned and justified above the left aligned and justified elements
- Submit button to be right aligned and justified

All of this is being done utilising flexboxes

Here is what I've got so far:

```css
/* Contact Page Styling */

.contact_left {
    flex-direction: row;
    flex: 1;
    align-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}

.contact_right {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex: 1;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.contact_form {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
}

.contact_form div {
    flex: 25%;
}

.contact_form div {
    flex: 50%;
}

.form_label {
    text-align: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    section {
        width: 80%;
    }
    
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  section {
        flex-direction: column;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 2px;
    }
  .contact_form {
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        align-content: flex-start;
    }

    .contact_form div { /* Change div elements to 100% */
        flex: 100%;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        align-content: flex-start;
    }

    .form_label { /* Align the text left */
        text-align: left;
    }
    
    .contact_input {
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        align-content: flex-start;
        flex: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<section>
<div class="contact_right">
            <form class="contact_form" id="contact_form">
                <div class="form_label">
                    <label for="contact_name">Full Name:</label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input class="contact_input" type="text" id="contact_name" name="contact_name" placeholder="Name">
                </div>
                <div class="form_label">
                    <label for="contact_email">Email Address:</label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="email" id="contact_email" name="contact_email" placeholder="Email">
                </div>
                <div class="form_label">
                    <label for="contact_number">Mobile Number:</label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="tel" id="contact_number" name="contact_number" placeholder="Mobile Number">
                </div>
                <div class="form_label">
                    <label for="contact_message">Message:</label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <textarea rows="4" cols="40" id="contact_message" name="contact_message" value=""></textarea> 
                </div>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
```

I noticed in the snippet above the formatting isn't as bad as what it looks like on the web-page: [Image of formatting with full website coding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/To8NF.png)

For those that have some spare time and would like to provide some feedback I have uploaded it all here: https://webchopper.000webhostapp.com/contact.html

[These are the wireframes of how the website is deemed to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4k1Ih.jpg)

Thanks so much for your help - any feedback is good feedback :-)

Comment: This is a serious suggestion. First, draw sketches of the layout(s) you want. That will help in planning your CSS.

Comment: Second, you’re over engineering the HTML. You don’t need `div` elements around everything, since CSS can handle any positioning you want.

Comment: @Manngo I have drawn layouts of every page for Desktop, Tablet and Phones. Hence why I am trying to develop the code enough now to display the intended look. This is the way I am being taught to do it in my TAFE course

Comment: Third, you’re using too many classes. Your target should be zero classes. Classes should be used only when there is no other way of describing an unknown number of similar elements. In this case, once you’ve got rid of the extraneous `div` elements, all the `label` elements are easily target with `form#form_contactform>label`.

Comment: “I have drawn layouts of every page for Desktop” - yes, but we haven’t seen the desired layout.

Comment: @Manngo as I said in my post - this is my first time coding a demo web page from scratch - I can only go by what I'm taught in my Diploma course. We have not been taught how to produce websites with minimal divs, and I've not been taught the code "form#form_contactform>label"

Comment: @Manngo everyones new once, support going into this field is greatly appreciated.

Comment: OK, so the form is provided by your TAFE? If so, I think they’re going about it the wrong way.

Comment: @Manngo correct - this is the way we were taught by our lecturer, and the way it is explained to us in all of the lecture sheets theyve handed us. Do you have a link that can explain this better for me - if I can come out better through all of this, that's the ultimate goal.

Comment: Here is a rough idea of what I was talking about: https://jsfiddle.net/wq5Lo90h/ . I notice that in your wire frames the labels are missing, which is not a good idea. The CSS has an extra block which you can enable for a layout puts the labels beside rather than above the inputs.

Comment: @Manngo Thank you so much ! I appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to some help above:

```css
p {
  text-align: center;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    margin: 5px auto;
}

form#contact_form {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: auto;
}

form#contact_form p {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    text-align: left;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding: 0;
}

form#contact_form p > label {
    display: flex;
    padding-right: 2px;
    text-align: left;
}


form#contact_form p > input,
form#contact_form p > textarea {
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 1em;
}

button {
    display: inline-block;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    width: 25%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact_right">
            <form id="contact_form">
                <p>
                    <label for="contact_name">Full Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="contact_name" name="contact_name" placeholder="Name">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="contact_email">Email Address:</label>
                    <input type="email" id="contact_email" name="contact_email" placeholder="Email">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="contact_number">Mobile Number:</label>
                    <input type="tel" id="contact_number" name="contact_number" placeholder="Mobile Number">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="contact_message">Message:</label>
                    <textarea rows="4" cols="40" id="contact_message" name="contact_message" placeholder="Message"></textarea> 
                </p>
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Now I'm just working on the positioning and formatting. As you can see the input boxes are a little off - and I want to align labels to the left.

Thanks for your help!